# use of 'as well as' with a modal verb

Tags: conjunctions

I have read many of sources about 'as well as' but honestly speaking even English users seem to be either confused on this or maybe no particular rule is in books. My actual confusion is about VERB FORM after 'as well as'. Some say there should be parallelism but some say that the next verb should be INGform... whatever the answer could be, there comes another difficulty for me. What form is to be used in this?

I must repent of this as well as leave this.

I must repent of this as well as leaving this.

I must repent of this as well as I leave this.

NOTE:I mean to say that I shouldn't only regret what I have done but also never do it again. This sentence isn't about the comparison of degrees.

Comment: You are asking us how we say something which we don't say. And you are using the word 'repent', which we very rarely use nowadays. We say, "I have to do this as well as that" and we say, "As well as doing this I have to do that." Your sentence might be written, "I must repent (of) what I did and also renounce it" or "As well as repenting (of) what I did I must also renounce it." (The use of 'of' seems to be optional.)

Comment: " Old Brixtonian Appreciative! My question is still there: Should we use 1ST FORM or ING-FORM of the verb after 'as well as'

Comment: Please find me an example. We DO say 'I'm painting as well as singing." We DON'T say "I paint as well as singing." If asked "Are you a professional painter?" we might reply "I sing as well as paint."

Comment: @ Old Brixtonian She is a talented musician as well as being a photographer. @ https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/well_1#well_idmg_1